# NodeList from .innerHTML to Array or String

Tags: javascript, arrays, html-table, innerhtml, nodelist

I am trying to save cell entries of a randomly sorted HTML table to a variable in JavaScript. I am so far that I get a nodeliste of the first column at the click of a button. My question is, how can I convert this NodeListe into an array? I have tried different things like `Array.prototype.slice.call (nl);` inside the `findOrder` function (inside `for` declaration) but it does not seem to have been very successful, since the individual entries appear as an array instead of all the entries in one array.

Working code:

```js
function randomSort()
{
  var row = document.getElementById("sort").rows;
  var rC = row.length;
  var tableBody = document.getElementById("idforparentnode").parentNode;
  for(i=0;i<rC;i++){
    tableBody.insertBefore(row[Math.ceil(Math.random()*(rC-1))],row[i]);
  }
}

function findOrder()
{
  var orderlist = document.getElementsByClassName("order");
  for (var i=0; i<orderlist.length; i++)
  {
    var nl = orderlist[i].innerHTML;
    console.log(nl);
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>Sort a HTML Table Randomly</title>
<body>

<p>Click the button to sort the table randomly:</p>

<p><button onclick="randomSort()">Shuffle Line 3-6</button></p>

<table border="1" id="myTable">
  <thead>
   <th style="display:none;"></th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Current Exchange Rate</th>
  </thead>

  <tbody class="avoid-sort">
    <tr>
      <td class="order" style="display:none;">1</td>
      <td>General Electric</td>
      <td>19,57</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="order" style="display:none;">2</td>
      <td>Johnson & Johnson</td>
      <td>119,14</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>

  <tbody id="sort">
    <tr id="idforparentnode">
      <td class="order" style="display:none;">3</td>
      <td>Microsoft</td>
      <td>65,92</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="order" style="display:none;">4</td>
      <td>Verizon</td>
      <td>40,82</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="order" style="display:none;">5</td>
      <td>American Express</td>
      <td>77,21</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="order" style="display:none;">6</td>
      <td>WhatSoEver</td>
      <td>12,34</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  
  <tbody class="avoid-sort">
    <tr>
      <td class="order" style="display:none;">7</td>
      <td>Apple</td>
      <td>133,90</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="order" style="display:none;">8</td>
      <td>Nintendo</td>
      <td>43,53</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="order" style="display:none;">9</td>
      <td>WhatEver</td>
      <td>999,99</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<br>
<input type="button" value="Display Order (based on standard order)" onclick="findOrder()">
<br>
<p>Display order of rows: </p> 
<p id="orderdisplay"></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: some things are not clear... how do you want to store the values inside the array? only the order number or all the data from the table row? is "nl" the array that you want to populate?

Comment: I try to be more specific. At the end I want to have a array or string that I can "print" to my placeholder `<p id="orderdisplay"></p>` like [1, 2, 4, 6, 5, 7, 8, 9] of the `order` (which is the class and represents the place of the row at the beginning). `nl` is so far the list of all inner HTML entries of the class `order`. To answer your question: in `nl` (or whatever the variable is called at the end) should be only the `order` number stored-not every entry of the row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`orderlist` is actually an `HTMLCollection`. You can convert `NodeList` or `HTMLCollection` to an `Array` using spread element

```js
function randomSort()
{
  var row = document.getElementById("sort").rows;
  var rC = row.length;
  var tableBody = document.getElementById("idforparentnode").parentNode;
  for(i=0;i<rC;i++){
    tableBody.insertBefore(row[Math.ceil(Math.random()*(rC-1))],row[i]);
  }
}

function findOrder()
{
  var orderlist = [...document.getElementsByClassName("order")];
  console.log(Array.isArray(orderlist));
  for (var i=0; i<orderlist.length; i++)
  {
    var nl = orderlist[i].innerHTML;
    console.log(nl);
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>Sort a HTML Table Randomly</title>
<body>

<p>Click the button to sort the table randomly:</p>

<p><button onclick="randomSort()">Shuffle Line 3-6</button></p>

<table border="1" id="myTable">
  <thead>
   <th style="display:none;"></th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Current Exchange Rate</th>
  </thead>

  <tbody class="avoid-sort">
    <tr>
      <td class="order" style="display:none;">1</td>
      <td>General Electric</td>
      <td>19,57</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="order" style="display:none;">2</td>
      <td>Johnson & Johnson</td>
      <td>119,14</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>

  <tbody id="sort">
    <tr id="idforparentnode">
      <td class="order" style="display:none;">3</td>
      <td>Microsoft</td>
      <td>65,92</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="order" style="display:none;">4</td>
      <td>Verizon</td>
      <td>40,82</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="order" style="display:none;">5</td>
      <td>American Express</td>
      <td>77,21</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="order" style="display:none;">6</td>
      <td>WhatSoEver</td>
      <td>12,34</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  
  <tbody class="avoid-sort">
    <tr>
      <td class="order" style="display:none;">7</td>
      <td>Apple</td>
      <td>133,90</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="order" style="display:none;">8</td>
      <td>Nintendo</td>
      <td>43,53</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="order" style="display:none;">9</td>
      <td>WhatEver</td>
      <td>999,99</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<br>
<input type="button" value="Display Order (based on standard order)" onclick="findOrder()">
<br>
<p>Display order of rows: </p> 
<p id="orderdisplay"></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: But still I have no array of the innerHTML of all `order`-classes, am I correct? e.g. if I print the variable into the placeholder `<p id="orderdisplay"></p>` by `document.getElementById("orderdisplay").innerHTML = str;` after converting the array to a string (`var str = nl.toString();`), it still shows only a single number.

Comment: If you are trying to get the `.innerHTML` of the elements into an array you can use `Array.from()` or chain `.map()` to `var orderlist = [...document.getElementsByClassName("order")].map(({innerHTML}) => innerHTML)`

Comment: That's it. Thank you!    `function findOrder(){
  var orderlist = [...document.getElementsByClassName("order")].map(({innerHTML})=>innerHTML);
  console.log(Array.isArray(orderlist));
  document.getElementById("orderdisplay").innerHTML=orderlist;
}`